# How to turn off cache?

Tags: http, caching, browser

How can I turn off browser caching for a specific website, so refreshing it with F5 works like refreshing it with ctrl + F5? I noticed that setting:

Cache-Control: no-cache

just doesn't work. And this caching spoils my website after hitting F5 because I'm not sure what it caches and there's a lot of dynamic actions there.

So there are two questions:

- How do I turn off this caching?
- How do I check what's being cached?

Answer (score 0):

There's any research effort…… Here's your answer for perfect no-cached content using HTML:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

==> from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/2213706.

And here's something about `If-Modified-Since` header:

==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192640/2213706

Comment: Doesn't work. There's still diffirence between hitting F5 and ctrl+F5 on my website

Comment: Wait... I think it helped a little bit but still not fully. I mean now the website is displayed properly under Chrome but for example Firefox still makes problems.

Comment: How can I check what's being loaded from cache when entering a website in Firefox?

Comment: You can list the cache in recent browsers using "about:cache" in the navbar. It's raw, but you can know which elements are cached. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the < head>

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

OR Ctrl + shift + R

OR Ctrl + F5

OR Delete Cache from browser

OR Private Browsing